# Piwik API integration

Tags: matomo

I'm trying to write some php to extract data from Piwik.  At the moment all I'm trying to do is get it to run the sample code but I can't.  I've installed it in a directory called analytics and my code is

```
            <?php
            use Piwik\API\Request;
            use Piwik\FrontController;
            echo "result script loaded";

            define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('../../')."/httpdocs/analytics/");
            define('PIWIK_USER_PATH', realpath('../../'."/httpdocs/analytics/"));
            define('PIWIK_ENABLE_DISPATCH', false);
            define('PIWIK_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
            define('PIWIK_ENABLE_SESSION_START', false);

            echo "<br/>1 PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH:  ".PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH;

            // if you prefer not to include 'index.php', you must also define here PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT
            // and include "libs/upgradephp/upgrade.php" and "core/Loader.php"
            require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "index.php";
            require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "core/API/Request.php";

            FrontController::getInstance()->init();

            // This inits the API Request with the specified parameters
            $request = new Request('
                        module=API
                        &method=Resolution.getResolution
                        &idSite=all
                        &date=last4
                        &period=month
                        &format=XML
                        &filter_limit=3
                        &token_auth=anonymous
            ');
            // Calls the API and fetch XML data back
            echo "<br/>here";

            $result = $request->process();
            echo $result;
            ?>
```

This runs but produces

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

so it is working a bit but not fully.  I can't find anything to help me so if you've any ideas I'd be grateful

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format your code. Erase all the echo of your code, except the last one. If you mix echo and XML, the XML output won't be correct. I don't know if in your real file you have all these blanks before each line, but in this case, erase them too.

As a result your code should be like this :

```
<?php
use Piwik\API\Request;
use Piwik\FrontController;

define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('../../')."/httpdocs/analytics/");
define('PIWIK_USER_PATH', realpath('../../'."/httpdocs/analytics/"));
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_DISPATCH', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_SESSION_START', false);

// if you prefer not to include 'index.php', you must also define here PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT
// and include "libs/upgradephp/upgrade.php" and "core/Loader.php"
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "index.php";
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "core/API/Request.php";

FrontController::getInstance()->init();

// This inits the API Request with the specified parameters
$request = new Request('
            module=API
            &method=Resolution.getResolution
            &idSite=all
            &date=last4
            &period=month
            &format=XML
            &filter_limit=3
            &token_auth=anonymous
');
// Calls the API and fetch XML data back
$result = $request->process();
echo $result;
```